# Error while turning a string into a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

This is for Jupyter Notebook/Google Colab/Pandas
the full number of my Latitude isn't showing up when I would run the code to convert a strong to a tuple.
[image: Output before I ran the code]

Code I ran

```
#convert LATLNG from string to tuple
new_LNGLAT=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    a=df['LATLNG'].iloc[i]
    new_LNGLAT.append((float(a[a.find(':')+2:a.find(',')]),float(a[a.find('-'):a.find('}')])))

df['LATLNG']=new_LNGLAT
```

[image: Output of dataframe after I ran the code]

Anyone know how to fix

Comment: You already have `lat` and `lon` columns, why do you need to extract the same values from this string?

Comment: Why are you using `a.find(':')`? There's no `:` character in the `LATLNG` column.

Comment: There's also no `}` character, what is `a.find('}')` supposed to find?

Comment: It looks like this code was designed to extract these values from a JSON object, but in that case you should use `json.loads()`

Comment: `a.find('-')` assumes that the longitude will always be negative.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. In your own words, step by step, how do you intend for the code to work? What do you think it means? Now, try to *test* that, a step at a time. Does each part of the calculation do what you expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be trying to extract from a string that't not formatted the same way that you show in the dataframe. The latitude and longitude are just separated by comma, there's no `:` or `}` characters. You can use the `split()` function to separate this.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    a=df['LATLNG'].iloc[i]
    lat, lon = a.split(',')
    new_LNGLAT.append((float(lat),float(lon)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try apply a lambda function:

```
df['LATLNG'] = df['LATLNG'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')) #This return a list
df['LATLNG'] = df['LATLNG'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x)) #Transform the list to tuple
```

Also this will work:

```
df['LATLNG'] = df['LATLNG'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['LATLNG'] = df['LATLNG'].str.split(',').apply(tuple)
```